How do I deal with mold on laminate floor under carpet?
Thanks for the help I appreciate it

Although mold can grow almost anywhere, the area of the suspected mold is atypical.  It appears to be towards center of the room.  Either you uncovered the tip of the iceberg, or this is an isolated area with a unique explanation.  Something appears to be generating a significant amount of moisture in the middle of the room, which is odd.  Were people or animals sleeping on the floor?  How long have you lived there?

Welcome. Have you searched? There are many existing questions on this topic.
